# Changing Language of Date Field in Mail Merge

Tags: microsoft-word, language, mail-merge

I'm running a mail merge on my laptop, set to English locale with Thai language as optional proofing language.

I've managed inserting the current date in Thai format (with months written in full Thai spelling).

However, I've got other dates from my mail merge recipient list which I also want to convert to a specific format. I've already added the format "dd MMMM yyyy" but I also need to specify the language (Thai in this case). What do I need to add in the field code to switch language?

`{MERGEFIELD meeting_date \@ "dd MMMM yyyy"`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by luck (story below).

The format would be:

`{MERGEFIELD meeting_date \@ "d ดดดด bbbb"}`

Which returns:

8 กันยายน 2560

*I found out this solution by using the insert date feature, where there is an option to select the language of the date format, and selected Thai language. Then I highlighted the date and used insert quickparts > fields and selected a date field, which magically beared the same Thai format. The field appeared in Thai format, so I toggled the field codes and discovered the syntax for Thai dates. Voilà.*